# How to get form id with js?

Tags: javascript

How to get a `form` element's `id` using JavaScript, when you have the `form` object.

Using `form.id` would be good, but if the `form` has an `<input id="id">` it returns that `input` object instead of the `id` of the `form` element.

Comment: `form.getAttribute("id")`

Comment: @cookie monster yes, you're right, but those are things you have to go with, when you're working with not your own code. If you write this as an answer, I will accept it as correct.

Comment: I misunderstood about the ID at first. I thought you had duplicate IDs on the page. Go ahead and accept one of the answers below. Don't wait for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getAttribute("id");` to get the id of the form.

Comment: how? Can you give an example please.